# How to use keyword VALUE as a field name in H2 database

Tags: h2, keyword

I inherited a project where in UnitTests an H2 database is being used. On the startup of the project a lot of tables are created and populated with data.

```
 CREATE TABLE SRC_FIELD_VALUE
   (    ID NUMBER IDENTITY,
        INPUT_SRC_FIELD_REF_ID NUMBER,
        VALUE VARCHAR2(255),
        DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(255)
   );
```

We recently migrated to the latest version of H2 : 2.1.214

In my POM.XML I added "NON_KEYWORDS=VALUE,ID" to the end of  definition but still got an exception :

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE SRC_FIELD_VALUE ( ID NUMBER IDENTITY, INPUT_SRC_FIELD_REF_ID NUMBER, [*]VALUE VARCHAR2(255),            DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(255) )"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE TC_RULE_COMP_DATA ( ID NUMBER IDENTITY, RULE_REF_ID NUMBER, SORT_ORDER NUMBER, VALUE CLOB ) [42001-214]
```

I also tried to put double quote around "VALUE" but got the same exception. It's interesting that "ID" is not getting considered as KEYWORD though.

What are my options here? I can't rename the fields.

Comment: `VALUE` is a reserved word in the SQL Standard and H2, it cannot be used as unquoted identifier. `ID` is not a reserved word. H2 has `NON_KEWORDS` setting, but you need to append `;NON_KEYWORDS=VALUE` to JDBC URL (and if you use Spring Boot, you need to disable automatic configuration for unit tests, otherwise your custom URL will be ignored).

Comment: Yes, I do use SpringBoot. How do you disable an automatic configuration? I tried adding "VALUE" to NON_KEYWORDS, but still didn't work throwing the same exception

Comment: You can use `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)` annotation on tests or `spring.test.database.replace=NONE` in properties file.

Answer (score 2):

VALUE is a reserved word in the SQL Standard and H2, it cannot be used as unquoted identifier.

The way to deal with this, in @SpringBootTest, is to configure the datasource url:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:thedatabase;NON_KEYWORDS=VALUE
```

PS: This answer was compiled from the comments from Evgenij

and to disable test database replace:

```
spring.test.database.replace=none
```